# Is there a constant by which I can multiply to invert one sign?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, constants

Take the equation $A(x - 7) = x + 7$. Is this possible?

In other words, is there any constant $A$ by which $(x - 7)$ can be multiplied to become $(x + 7)$?

Notes:

- $x$ is any real number.
- The original question was $x + 7 = A(x - 7) + B(x + 5)$. I thought I'd be clever and set $B$ to $0$, but I realized I had no idea what $A$ should be.

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$? Real numbers? And does a single constant $A$ need to work for all of these values?

Comment: @wgrenard $x$ and $y$ are real numbers; yes, a single constant $A$ must work for both.

Comment: Such an $A$ doesn't exists since you could choose $y=2x$ or $y=3x$ and get different $A$s

Comment: @112 is this really a question about "a mathematical constant that is interesting in some way"?

Comment: All right; I'll clarify a bit, I accept that it was too generic...

Comment: @112 what you are proposing causes more problems than it is worth. You should instead solve for the $x$ coefficient and constant coefficient.

Comment: Is it really unclear what this question is asking? I find it quite straightforward: a) Is there a constant $A$ independent of variable $x$  such that $A(x+7)=(x-7)$. The answer is clearly "No". As a followup, "Then how do I solve this problem" which has a clear solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such constant that does not depend on $x$ and $y$.  Just try a few examples.  For $x=3,y=1$ you would need $A=2$.  For $x=5,y=1$ you would need $A=\frac 32$  The fact that these are different shows it is not possible.  Why would you think it is?

Answer (score 1):

A very quick way to see this is impossible is to consider the case that $x=y\neq 0$.  Then $x-y=0$ and so $A(x-y)=0$ no matter what $A$ is, but $x+y=2x$ is nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the actual problem consider collecting everything to one side.

You will notice that overall the equation of $(x-Ax-Bx)+(7+7A-5B)=0$ must be 0 independent of choice of $x$. What does that tell you about the relationship between $A$ and $B$? You will also note the constant term must be 0, what does that tell you about $A$ and $B$? Can you relate the expressions to solve for $A$ and $B$? (2 equations, 2 unknowns)